# Gatling - Is there way to run multiple simulation files at the same

Tags: performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I have multiple simulation files testing multiple scenarios. I would like to run all of them at the same time in windows. Is there a programmatic or a commandline way to run all the simulations from each file

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is: No.

You can find more information about that here: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/FxUENg9v2g4

Anyway, you can simply regroup all your scenarios into different classes to have one simulation that runs multiple scenarios.