# Gatling - How to Run Multiple Gatling simulations in parallel

Tags: scala, gatling

I want to run my multiple Gatling simulations scala files at the same time.

I have three Simulations scala files

1. Brand1_AllSenariosSimulation.scala
2. Brand2_AllSenariosSimulation.scala
3. Brand3_AllSenariosSimulation.scala

I need to run all above scala file at same time , Please let me know how is it possible.

**Is this below Comment true for gatling** ?

[image]

Comment: The screenshot is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948731/gatling-is-there-way-to-run-multiple-simulation-files-at-the-same The link on screenshot is https://groups.google.com/g/gatling/c/FxUENg9v2g4

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this answer is correct. That’s not how you should be structuring your tests with Gatling.

You should aim at running scenarios in parallel inside a single simulation, not running simulations in parallel.